# Элемент который появляется каждый раз при переписке с пользователем

Tags: php, sql

Как сделать просмотр сообщений и чтобы каждый новый день отмечался как в сообщениях Discord?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$user_2 = htmlspecialchars(trim(stripslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user_2']))));
$mess = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `gialog` WHERE (`user_1` = '{$myInfo['unicalCode']}' AND `user_2` = '$user_2') OR (`user_2` = '{$myInfo['unicalCode']}' AND `user_1` = '$user_2')  ") or die (mysqli_error($connection));

while ($message = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mess) ) {
    else {
        echo '
            <div class="wrap_message">
                <img class="avatar_sender" border="true" src="images/users/user.png">
                <div class="wrap_info_sender">
                    <span class="name_sender transition_link">Имя</span>
                    <span class="time_sender">'.$message['time'].'</span>
                </div>
                <div class="text_message">'.$message['message'].'</div>
            </div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: ну очевидно же - при выводе переписки разделять сообщения, относящиеся к разным дням с помощью разметки..

Comment: Только я не знаю как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала необходимо описать метод, извлекающий дату из входящих данных. Надеюсь проблем с ним не возникнет.

```
...
public function getDate(string $rawDateTime): string
{
    // в методе getDate() в зависимости от входящих данныъх
    // опишите получение даты в любом формате, в Вашем случае строки:
    return '12 июля 2020 г';
}
...
```

Затем в каждой итерации с его помощью получаете дату для текущего сообщения (getDate($message['time'])) и сравниваете её с предыдущей ($date):

```
$date = '';
while ($message = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mess)) {
    $date = getDate($message['time']);
    
    // если дата изменилась - добавляем разделительный блок
    if ($date !== getDate($message['time'])) {
        echo "<div class='separation_block'>$date</div>" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '
        <div class="wrap_message">
            <img class="avatar_sender" border="true" src="images/users/user.png">
            <div class="wrap_info_sender">
                <span class="name_sender transition_link">Имя</span>
                <span class="time_sender">' . $message['time'] . '</span>
            </div>
            <div class="text_message">' . $message['message'] . '</div>
        </div>';
}
```

Вам осталось только написать разметку для `<div class='separation_block'>`.

ЗЫ: убрал лишний блок `else` из Вашего кода.